# pip installs modules for python 2.7

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip, pydub

I want to install a module with pip, in my case pydub.
However `pip install pydub` installs pydub in `/home/<user>/.local/lib/python2.7/`

So when I run my script
`python3 myScript.py`
it tells me
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydub'`

How do I get pip to install pydub for 3.x rather than 2.7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pip3 install xxx`, or better yet, `python3 -m pip install xxx`. The problem here is that by default `pip` is aliased to python2's installation.